# .gitignore does not seem to ignore files

Tags: git, visual-studio, gitignore

I have added a .gitignore into my project, but It seems that It don't ignore certain files:

```
   modified:   .gitignore
    modified:   src/INT.InformationServices.OnePlmSub/Startup.cs
    modified:   src/OnePlmSub.Domain.Abstract/IAttributeService.cs
    modified:   src/OnePlmSub.Domain.Abstract/ISalesItemService.cs
    modified:   src/OnePlmSub.Domain.Abstract/IServiceKitService.cs
    modified:   src/OnePlmSub.Domain.Abstract/ISparePartService.cs
    modified:   src/OnePlmSub.Domain.Abstract/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/OnePlmSub.Domain.Abstract.dll
    modified:   src/OnePlmSub.Domain.Abstract/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/OnePlmSub.Domain.Abstract.pdb
    modified:   src/OnePlmSub.Domain.Abstract/obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/OnePlmSub.Domain.Abstract.csproj.CoreCompileInputs.cache
    modified:   src/OnePlmSub.Domain.Abstract/obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/OnePlmSub.Domain.Abstract.dll
    modified:   src/OnePlmSub.Domain.Abstract/obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/OnePlmSub.Domain.Abstract.pdb
    modified:   src/OnePlmSub.Domain.Configuration/Injections.cs
    modified:   src/OnePlmSub.Domain.Configuration/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/OnePlmSub.Domain.Abstract.dll
    modified:   src/OnePlmSub.Domain.Configuration/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/OnePlmSub.Domain.Abstract.pdb
    modified:   src/OnePlmSub.Domain.Configuration/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/OnePlmSub.Domain.Configuration.dll
    modified:   src/OnePlmSub.Domain.Configuration/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/OnePlmSub.Domain.Configuration.pdb
    modified:   src/OnePlmSub.Domain.Configuration/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/OnePlmSub.Domain.dll
    modified:   src/OnePlmSub.Domain.Configuration/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/OnePlmSub.Domain.pdb
    modified:   src/OnePlmSub.Domain.Configuration/obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/OnePlmSub.Domain.Configuration.dll
    modified:   src/OnePlmSub.Domain.Configuration/obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/OnePlmSub.Domain.Configuration.pdb
    modified:   src/OnePlmSub.Domain/ProductService.cs
    modified:   src/OnePlmSub.Domain/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/OnePlmSub.Domain.Abstract.dll
    modified:   src/OnePlmSub.Domain/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/OnePlmSub.Domain.Abstract.pdb
    modified:   src/OnePlmSub.Domain/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/OnePlmSub.Domain.dll
    modified:   src/OnePlmSub.Domain/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/OnePlmSub.Domain.pdb
    modified:   src/OnePlmSub.Domain/obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/OnePlmSub.Domain.csproj.CoreCompileInputs.cache
    modified:   src/OnePlmSub.Domain/obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/OnePlmSub.Domain.dll
    modified:   src/OnePlmSub.Domain/obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/OnePlmSub.Domain.pdb
```

As you can see, It don't ignore the files in the bin/ and obj/ folders.

My .gitignore can be found here https://pastecode.io/s/05bcoo9afk

Anyone who have an Idea?

Answer (score 0):

`.gitignore` will not ignore files that are already added to git. By the fact that they are in `modified` state, we can tell that they are already in git.

If they were not supposed to be in git in the first place, you can remove them and make a commit of that removal. (And probably push it.) Then, as long as your `.gitignore` is correct, they will no longer show up.

Comment: should I just delete the files and then try to push it?

Comment: That's what I'd suggest. `git rm` the files, commit, push. (`git rm` is just a plain `rm` followed by a `git add` to tell git that you mean it.)